# Easiest way to play mp3 files in python to a specific device

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, mp3, hardware, playback

I'm converting an ESP32 project to a Raspberry Pi zero. One of the project behaviors is to play back sound effects based on specific events or triggers. I prefer to use MP3 format so I can store information about the contents of the file in the ID3TAGs to make the files themselves easier to manage. (there are a lot of them!)

I can find examples of using any number of libraries to play mp3s in python, and I found an example of selecting a device using 'sounddevice' but it seems to want numpy arrays to play sound data.

I'm wondering what the easiest and quickest way is to play mp3 files (or should I go to some other file format with a data stub file for each to do my file management?).

Since these behaviors are played as responses, they need to at least start playback quickly (i.e. not wait for a format conversion to take place). And in some cases, other behaviors (such as voice recognition triggers) are already going to add to potential latency on the device in it's total response time.

EDIT: additional info

quickest means processor speed (pi zeros slow down quick under heavy load)
These are real time responses so any 'lag' converting defeats the purpose of the playback.
Also, the device from seeed is configured as an alsa (asound) device

Comment: Scott, you surely know that asking for 'easiest and quickest' is a subjective question? [Questions to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: easiest and quickest in this context refers to the platform. Pi zeros get bogged down fast. I need the least processor intensive way of doing it as fast as possible time-wise. (preferably in a controllable way - system calls to mpg321, for example, may be harder to 'stop' if needed)